# Meteor.call raises exception even with a callback function

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-methods

I have the Meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  orderStatusUpdate: function(orderId, status, note) {
    check(orderId, String);

    var statusData = {
      status: status,
    }
    if (note) {
      statusData.statusNote = note;
    }
    check(statusData, SchemaCompiled.orderStatus);

    Collections.orders.update({_id: orderId}, {$set: statusData});
  }
});
```

with custom validation on field `statusNote`:

```
custom: function(){
  if (someCondition) {
    return 'required';
  }
  return false;
}
```

My issue is that even with a callback function defined:

```
Meteor.call('orderStatusUpdate', orderId, orderStatus, note, function (error, result) {
  // doing something
}
```

the Exception is logged to Console:

> Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'orderStatusUpdate' errorClass {message: "Match error: Note is required", path: "", sanitizedError: errorClass, errorType: "Match.Error", invalidKeys: Array[1]} Error: Match error: Note is required

As I understand the exception is raised when I call `check(...)`.

How can I catch this exception to properly show it to the customer?

BTW, the callback function also is called with the `error` variable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raised/logged exception has nothing to do with the callback or lack thereof.

If the method is defined in a shared folder (that is evaluated by both the client and the server), a *stub* will be run on the client. If it throws anything, the error is normally caught and logged to console.

The callback is only related to the server-side run.

You have a number of ways to handle this:

1. Define the method server-only (in the *server* folder).

   This will make the method run on the server only, so the error will be received on the client.
2. Catch it on the client and do something about it, as @ChristianFritz suggested.
3. Use a (currently) undocumented feature (`throwStubExceptions`) that, in case the stub throws an exception, throws the exception and prevents the server method from being called:

   On both the client and the server:

   ```js
   Meteor.methods({
     thrower: function() {
       throw 'catchMe!';
     }
   });
   ```

   Then, on the client:

   ```js
   try{
     Meteor.apply('thrower', [], {throwStubExceptions: true}, function(err, res){
       console.log('err!', err);
     })  
   } catch(e) {
     console.log('caught', e);
   }
   ```

   This code will catch the error and log `caught catchMe!`, and the method will not be called on the server.

Comment: looks nice the idea of stubException, but how do I tell autoForm to mark the field with invalid error and show the error in this case?

Comment: I am not sure. AutoForm has a `method` type form that calls a method you specify, but I did not use it.

Comment: your solution (3) removes the exception, and as you said it is not calls the method in server after error. But it also doesn't shows the error in autoForm, when with exceptions the error appears in the form. Any clue?

Comment: When using 1 or 2, the exception is caught. I don't see what is wrong with that. AutoForm most likely uses the `error` argument to from the callback and ignores the stub, but I did not verify this. You can define it on both client and server and throw the exception. Behavior may be different between the two, depending on the type of data you have available. You can also define the two methods differently.

Comment: Thank you man, it works perfect. The (3) solution. Do you think it will be changed in Meteor new version? as it is not documented

Comment: I don't know. IIRC, it was merged in from a PR in April. BTW, what was the matter with your original solution? Was the fact that you did not catch it on the client? Since the server state is the one that should be taken into account, I guess AutoForm simply waits for it and ignores the client throws, which may have been caused by data that is not available to the client. I think that this is a reasonable course of action and I would use (3) in very specific cases, and I'm not sure that this one is a prime example of such case.

Comment: The catch solution mentioned by Christian also works. I didn't resolved the autoform issue, in my case it is only one field, I made it out of autoform, will dig on it later. throwStubExeptions looks more elegant for me. Hopefully Meteor will preserve it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just catch it?

```js
try {
  check(statusData, SchemaCompiled.orderStatus);
} catch (e) {
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    alert(e);
  }
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Note that the exception is thrown in the *simulated* version of the method, i.e., on the client directly. The server-side exception will be passed in the `error` of the callback, but the client side code throws directly. The above should catch this.

Comment: in this case how do I send back the error to the autoForm instead of ```alert(e)``` ?